# (C) Reading from a Text File to a Structure

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I am trying to read multiple different data types (char, int, float) from a text file directly into a Structure.

```
readData() {
char filename[100];
int linesread;
int i = 0;

printf("Enter the assets text file that you wish to read: \n");
scanf("%s", filename);

if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening data file\n");
    readData();
} else {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %c %s %lf %lf %d %d %d", &assets[i].name, &assets[i].type, &assets[i].location, &assets[i].longi, &assets[i].lati, &assets[i].speed, &assets[i].fuelTime, &assets[i].readyTime != EOF)) {
        i++;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
linesread = i;

for (i = 0; i < linesread; i++) {
    printf("%s %s %s %lf %lf %d %d %d\n", &assets[i].name, &assets[i].type, &assets[i].location, &assets[i].longi, &assets[i].lati, &assets[i].speed, &assets[i].fuelTime, &assets[i].readyTime);
}
```

This Should read this out (when it decides to co-operate) and save it into the structure:

```
 Angle_Lifeboat L Angle 51.685 -5.102 25.0 600 120
 Angle_ILB L Angle 51.685 -5.102 25.0 180 30
 Broad_Haven_ILB L Broad_Haven 51.713 -5.113 25.0 180 30
```

But instead reads this

```
ngle_Lifeboat LAngle Angle 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4231936 4231940
Angle_ILB LAngle Angle 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4232008 4232012
Broad_Haven_ILB LBroad_Haven Broad_Haven 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 4232080 4232084
```

I am pretty new to C, so go easy on me. Any help you can give would be massively appreciated

EDIT: Stucture -->

```
 typedef struct assets{
char name[25];
char type[1];
float longi;
float lati;
char location[20];
int speed;
int fuelTime;
int readyTime;
 } assets;
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of your `struct`.

Comment: `!= EOF` bad position.

Comment: Edited the position of EOF

Answer (score 0):

```
fread(&my_struct, sizeof(my_struct), 1, fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In c programming i do think there is already an in build function to do the above ...
try using fread http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm

Comment: Suggestions/Thinking are not answers to such questions

Comment: Any help is pretty great. 'fread' looks useful, could someone give me some suggestions on how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

- BLUEPIXY correctly noticed the *`!= EOF` bad position*; correct is:

  ```
  … &assets[i].readyTime) != EOF) {
  ```
- We cannot print the character in `assets[i].type` as a string with `%s`, because that 1-char-array `type[1]` doesn't have (room for) the terminating null character; we must print it as a string with *precision* `.1` or a character:

  ```
  printf("…%.1s…\n", …assets[i].type…);   // need no & operator
  ```

  or

  ```
  printf("…%c…\n", …*assets[i].type…);    // need * operator
  ```
- The conversion specification `%lf` is for a pointer to `double` (rather than `float`); the `float`s need the conversion specification `%f`.
- Since the `speed` values are `25.0`, we cannot read them as integers with `%d`; we rather need to read a `float` variable with `%f`, either a temporary variable which is then assigned to `assets[i].speed`, or by defining `float speed;` in `assets`.